# Why is it faster to implement :hidden using offsetWidth and offsetHeight?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, dom

So I was looking through some older jquery release notes and found this.

```
    This is how the logic has changed:
* In jQuery 1.3.1 (and older) an element was visible if its CSS “display” was not “none”, its CSS “visibility” was not “hidden”, and its type (if it was an input) was not “hidden”.
* In jQuery 1.3.2 an element is visible if its browser-reported offsetWidth or offsetHeight is greater than 0.
```

In the release notes they did this for performance reasons.

Why would changing the implementation in this way result in such a performance benefit?

You can see the performance difference in

http://blog.jquery.com/2009/02/20/jquery-1-3-2-released/

Answer (score 0):

Well, they basically cut on number of checks.

v 1.3.1 was checking `style.visibility`, `style.display` and `type`

v 1.3.2 was checking only `offsetWidth` and `offsetHeight` properties (which, I believe, is 'cached' somehow in DOM implementation)

v 1.3.1:

```
Sizzle.selectors.filters.hidden = function(elem){
    return "hidden" === elem.type ||
    jQuery.css(elem, "display") === "none" ||
    jQuery.css(elem, "visibility") === "hidden";
};

Sizzle.selectors.filters.visible = function(elem){
return "hidden" !== elem.type &&
    jQuery.css(elem, "display") !== "none" &&
    jQuery.css(elem, "visibility") !== "hidden";
};
```

v 1.3.2

```
Sizzle.selectors.filters.hidden = function(elem){
    return elem.offsetWidth === 0 || elem.offsetHeight === 0;
};

Sizzle.selectors.filters.visible = function(elem){
    return elem.offsetWidth > 0 || elem.offsetHeight > 0;
};
```